# Populate /dev in Buildroot

Tags: modules, buildroot

I would like the `/dev/i2c*` devices to be populated in Buildroot for Pi zero after the `i2c_dev` module is inserted. Currently just modprobing the module does nothing. According the Buildroot doc I guess I should try to go the `devtmpfs + mdev` way, is that correct? Any additional hints regarding this topic? (Just waiting for rebuild ;-)

Answer (score 1):

OK. I can confirm that

- using the Buildroot `System Configuration | /dev management | Dynamic using devtmpfs + mdev`
- together with having `dtparam=i2c_arm=on` in `/boot/config.txt`

does the trick. After loading `i2c_dev` module the `/dev/i2c-1` is created.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem on my RPi 1, and it was necessary to load the i2c_bcm2835 module.